# Facing exception in Eureka after updating to newest JDBC driver in zuul and auth

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka, mssql-jdbc

Updated to newest JDBC driver version 12.2.0.jre8 in zuul and auth microservice. Initially everything was working fine but after updating the drivers facing exception in Eureka service:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:411)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:269)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:63)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:290)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d19f93d.CGLIB$eurekaClient$2(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d19f93d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d5772fc0.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d19f93d.eurekaClient(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create Jersey client
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.EurekaJerseyClientImpl$EurekaJerseyClientBuilder.build(EurekaJerseyClientImpl.java:182)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory$JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactoryBuilder.buildLegacy(JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.java:230)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory$JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactoryBuilder.build(JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.java:204)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.create(JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.java:161)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.Jersey1TransportClientFactories.newTransportClientFactory(Jersey1TransportClientFactories.java:59)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.scheduleServerEndpointTask(DiscoveryClient.java:485)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:398)
        ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create Jersey client
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.EurekaJerseyClientImpl.<init>(EurekaJerseyClientImpl.java:61)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.EurekaJerseyClientImpl$EurekaJerseyClientBuilder.build(EurekaJerseyClientImpl.java:180)
        ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:182)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:175)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:343)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:119)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:192)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:188)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:188)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4.<init>(ApacheHttpClient4.java:151)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4.<init>(ApacheHttpClient4.java:137)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4.create(ApacheHttpClient4.java:181)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.EurekaJerseyClientImpl.<init>(EurekaJerseyClientImpl.java:53)
        ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:152)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)
        at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:179)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.<clinit>(MediaTypes.java:65)
        ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:114)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:207)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:135)
        ... 84 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Looks like an incompatibility between Eureka and the JDBC driver. Perhaps in the Eureka documentation it states what JDBC driver versions are supported. You may have to update Eureka.

Comment: @Abra, We have updated JDBC driver in zuul server. We didnt add any jdbc driver for Eureka service. Getting exception in Eureka after deploying Zuul.What are the versions compatible between Eureka and the JDBC driver?

Comment: Class `org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl` is **not** on the CLASSPATH (or module path). Do you know where this class is supposed to be? (My guess is that it is in a JAR file.)